# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate to display a pop up screen on top of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have used a UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate to display another ViewController on top of a UITableViewController.

This helped avoid replacing existing UITableViewController(s) with a view controller + table (or hacking the combined component to display a view that does not scroll with the table on top of the table).

This was working fine until I tried adding didSelectRow on the Table object. Although the (pop up) view controller works ok, when dismissed, the following issues started (all associated with the navigation controller):

1. toolbar - I have a tool bar on screen (always shown). On dismissing the (pop up) view controller, the toolbar changes status to 'hidden' (setting 'hidden' to false brought it back).
2. on screen (floating) buttons (owned by the nav controller) - if these were displayed, they now 'disappear'. Checking the x, y coordinates, showed that their position has not changed but it looks as if they've been pushed backward from a view layering perspective).

Any ideas? Has anyone encountered this behaviour?

tested on the following devices: 4s, 5, 6/6p, 6s/6sp.

All devices showed the same issue except iPhone 6 (1st gen).

Tested with ios versions 9.2, 9.2.1, 9.3, 9.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

The issues were caused as a result of displaying the view using the 'current'/presenting VC as oppose to presenting via the navigation controller. Once changed, it all worked as expected.